# Make Foundation 6 toggle switch move all the way over?

Tags: zurb-foundation

In the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/L4a8cbqw/ there is a toggle switch.  When its clicked the white box does not slide all the way to the right, it stops half way. This is because I resized the switch.  How do I get the white box to slide all the way over to the right no matter how wide the toggle switch is?

```
<div class="switch large">
        <input class="switch-input" id="largeSwitch" type="checkbox" name="exampleSwitch">
        <label class="switch-paddle" for="largeSwitch" style="width: 7rem !important; font-weight: bold;">
            <span class="show-for-sr">Show Large Elephants</span>
                <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Off</span>
                <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">Show</span>            
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't thing you can solve this without directly modifying the foundation css.

Comment: I tried that but could not find where.  All the switch-? styles I looked at and none of them would push it over to the right all the way.   There has to be a setting somewhere that decides how far it moves, I just can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS should do it:

```
.switch.large input:checked ~ .switch-paddle:after {
  left: 4.75rem;
}
```